# Remove ThreadContext Properties

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, logging, log4net

I have set the ThreadContext.Properties and need to update its value during the life-cycle of my code.  In the past I have used log4j MDC and had to:
MDC.remove(TRACKING);

and then add another value by:
MDC.put(TRACKING, trackingIdStr);

Now that I am using Log4Net, our app uses Properties:
log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["TrackingId"] = tracker;

Question:  How do I remove the previous value and add a new value?  Is it as easy as just:
log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["TrackingId"] = tracker2;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is that easy.  You can reassign as you have shown in your question or you can remove the value altogether when you are finished with it.

```
//set
ThreadContext.Properties["TrackingId"] = tracker1;

//reset
ThreadContext.Properties["TrackingId"] = tracker2;

//completely remove
ThreadContext.Properties.Remove("TrackingId");
```

If you want your context properties to be in effect for a specific section of code (via using) then you can try ThreadContext.Stacks:

```
using(ThreadContext.Stacks["TrackingId"].Push("hello"))
{
  //messages logged here will be tagged with TrackingId="hello"
}
//messages logged here will not be tagged with TrackingId="hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this does not directly answer your question, but in your situation you might consider to use calculated context values. This is explained nicely here:

[Log4Net Tutorial pt 6: Log Event Context](http://www.beefycode.com/post/Log4Net-Tutorial-pt-6-Log-Event-Context.aspx)

(scroll down a bit)